# Is this an efficient or even correct way of parsing serial data?

Tags: java, hashmap, serial-port, serial-communication

To preface I am new to java (so take it ez on me lol) but here is what I am trying to do:

I have a GPS puck that I am reading via usb. The GPS puck uses some UI but I am trying to capture the data so I can use for my own application. I am reading in the packet from the serial buffer and trying to strip it down to just the payload and dissect the fields into a hashMap (not sure if this is the right application for it or not).

I want to add that the reason I care about efficiency in this case is because data will be getting processed through every fairly rapidly as the GPS puck is constantly getting Sat data (approx. every 200/300ms), so I am trying to avoid any bottlenecking if possible.

Here is the code that I have dished out, I know that in the code the buffer is not reading anything but in an effort to remove redundant code, just assume the data written in the comments is what we would be saying if we sys.out.

```
/* 

Assume this is serial data received from GPS serial packet:
B5 62 01 02 1C AA AA AA AA 01 02 03 04 0A 0B 0C 0D B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2 C3 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4 E1 E2 E3 E4 01 02;
     |  |   /  |                                                                                      /  |  
     |  \ len   \                                                                                    /  CRC
    /    |       \                                                                                  /
   /     |        \                                 PAYLOAD                                        /
Header   |         \                                                                              /
    class & id      \                                                                            /

*/
HashMap<String, String> payloadDict = new HashMap<String, String> (); // HashMap to write to

Bytes[] buffer; // serial buffer
String byteToHex = DataTypeConverter.parseHexBinary(buffer); // converts byte data to string in Hex

// Since the first few fields in the packet are static (header, class & id, and len),
// I strip the HEX string to only contain the payload
int payloadStartIndex = byteToHex.indexOf("C") + 1;
String payload = byteToHex.substring(payloadStartIndex, payloadStartIndex + 29);

/*

Assume this is the payload string after we parse:

AA AA AA AA 01 02 03 04 0A 0B 0C 0D B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2 C3 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4 E1 E2 E3 E4
**added seperation every 2 hex values for readability,
  but assume it's just one giant string

*/

// write to HashMap
payloadDict = NAV_POSLLH(payload);


/*

so to visualize what I would imagine being saved to the HashMap:

iTOW:   AA AA AA AA 
lon:    01 02 03 04 
lat:    0A 0B 0C 0D 
height: B1 B2 B3 B4 
hMSL:   C1 C2 C3 C4 
hAcc:   D1 D2 D3 D4 
vAcc:   E1 E2 E3 E4

*/


public Map<String, String> NAV_POSLLH(String dataArr) {
    // Temp HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String, String> ();

    /*
        this is the payload format.
        payloadStructure are the names of the all the fields I want to parse
        and hexOffset are the beginning of each field.      
    */

    String[] payloadStructure = new String[6] {"iTOW", "lon", "lat", "height", "hMSL", "hAcc", "vAcc"};
    int[] hexOffset = new int[6] {0, 7, 11, 15, 20, 24};



    // loop through each field 
    for(int i = 0; i < byteOffset.length; i++) {
        String parse = "";

        // I am not sure if this is the best way to handle out of index errors
        // in java, but this is what I thought would work
        if(byteOffset[i] == 24) {
            parse = dataArr.substring(hexOffset[i]);
            map.put(payloadStructure[i], parse);
            return dict;
        }

        // parse the substring from the beginning of each hex offset
        // to the next index -1
        parse = dataArr.substring(byteOffset[i], hexOffset[i+1] -1);
        map.put(payloadStructure[i], parse);

        // finally return HashMap
        return dict;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the comments explain the packet structure well enough or if it is confusing (because the format is janky), so I attached a screenshot of the packet layout I made.

[image: Serial packet layout]

So what I am trying to ask from all of this:
Based on what I am trying to accomplish, is this an efficient or even a correct way of implementing it? I am not sure if there is anything I am just obviously missing.

I am unable to compile or test any code right now so I am just trying to visualize what the output would be haha. Thanks so much for anyone's input!

Comment: It's certainly not efficient. This is probably irrelevant; that puck is sending 1 byte of data in the same timeframe that your CPU can process a few million of them, so taking 100x longer than you needed to will be completely unnoticable. Do not convert bytes to Strings if you want efficiency. I'd try to look up how to write binary protocols, as what you're doing is not just incredibly inefficient, but probably also much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Also, to be clear, nothing about the format seems janky to me. In fact, having everything set up to be a 4-byte width fixed size construct seems solid and simple to parse. Don't blame the protocol for this.

Comment: Is this the native GPS format or a custom (relatively sane) one defined by the device?

Comment: Is it easier and more accurate to use these libraries? [NMEA Java Library](http://nmealib.sourceforge.net/), [ktuukkan/marine-api](https://github.com/ktuukkan/marine-api), [elstepherino/InvernessPark.Android.Utilities.NMEA](https://github.com.cnpmjs.org/elstepherino/InvernessPark.Android.Utilities.NMEA), [NMEA 0183 sentence parser/builder](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/279647/NMEA-0183-sentence-parser-builder)

Comment: @rzwitserloot thanks for the response! I'll research on binary protocols. Just to note-- what I meant by janky format is the block comment I made trying to label the packet format. Nothing to do with the actual format of the protocol itself!

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- This is the UBX-NAV-POSLLH Protocol by U-box. I can use the U-blox UI to program what protocols I want the Puck to dish out. I refer to this [doc](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox8-M8_ReceiverDescrProtSpec_UBX-13003221.pdf)

Comment: @kunif Thanks so much for referring these libraries! I'm kicking myself right now that wasn't the first thing I looked up. I'll dive into these and see if they are more practical for my use case! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `Packet` class and fill it using `ByteBuffer`. That class has great methods for parsing, including bulk get methods for various primitive sizes. You might consider using a `ByteBuffer` for the payload member of that class

Comment: I will definitely give a look into this java library. Thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: No problem. Out of interest, what's the hardware?

Comment: VK-162 G-Mouse! Really inexpensive GPS Nav Dongle.

Comment: Nice. Best of luck with the parser